# ClojureScript Parameter Declaration Error

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I was hacking away happily with clojurescript, when suddenly this error cropped up:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration clojure.core/let should be a vector
>                   core.clj:6567 clojure.core/assert-valid-fdecl
>                    core.clj:220 clojure.core/sigs

I have tried commenting all bits of code, restarted the server etc ..... I am using cljsbuild 0.2.1 for comiplation. How do I debug this error?

Below is the complete stacktrace, and it doesnt show which line could be causing the error -

```
Compiling "resources/public/cljs/client.js" failed:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter declaration clojure.core/let should be a vector
                core.clj:6567 clojure.core/assert-valid-fdecl
                 core.clj:220 clojure.core/sigs
                 core.clj:294 clojure.core/defn
              RestFn.java:146 clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo
                 core.clj:605 clojure.core/apply
            compiler.clj:1394 cljs.compiler/macroexpand-1
            compiler.clj:1411 cljs.compiler/analyze-seq
            compiler.clj:1468 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1416 cljs.compiler/analyze-seq
            compiler.clj:1468 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1461 cljs.compiler/analyze
             compiler.clj:829 cljs.compiler/analyze-block
            compiler.clj:1036 cljs.compiler/eval1347[fn]
             MultiFn.java:177 clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke
            compiler.clj:1414 cljs.compiler/analyze-seq
            compiler.clj:1468 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1416 cljs.compiler/analyze-seq
            compiler.clj:1468 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1461 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1487 cljs.compiler/analyze-file
            compiler.clj:1153 cljs.compiler/analyze-deps
            compiler.clj:1187 cljs.compiler/eval1420[fn]
             MultiFn.java:177 clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke
            compiler.clj:1414 cljs.compiler/analyze-seq
            compiler.clj:1468 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1461 cljs.compiler/analyze
            compiler.clj:1529 cljs.compiler/compile-file*
            compiler.clj:1567 cljs.compiler/compile-file
            compiler.clj:1628 cljs.compiler/compile-root
              closure.clj:367 cljs.closure/compile-dir
              closure.clj:399 cljs.closure/eval2024[fn]
              closure.clj:266 cljs.closure/eval1952[fn]
              closure.clj:413 cljs.closure/eval2011[fn]
              closure.clj:266 cljs.closure/eval1952[fn]
              closure.clj:877 cljs.closure/build
              compiler.clj:49 cljsbuild.compiler/compile-cljs[fn]
              compiler.clj:48 cljsbuild.compiler/compile-cljs
             compiler.clj:116 cljsbuild.compiler/run-compiler
             NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 user/eval2452[fn]
              LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
              LazySeq.java:60 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
                  RT.java:473 clojure.lang.RT.seq
                 core.clj:133 clojure.core/seq
                core.clj:2725 clojure.core/dorun
                core.clj:2741 clojure.core/doall
             NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 user/eval2452
           Compiler.java:6511 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
           Compiler.java:6501 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
           Compiler.java:6500 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
           Compiler.java:6501 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
           Compiler.java:6477 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                core.clj:2797 clojure.core/eval
                 main.clj:297 clojure.main/eval-opt
                 main.clj:316 clojure.main/initialize
                 main.clj:349 clojure.main/null-opt
                 main.clj:427 clojure.main/main
              RestFn.java:421 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                 Var.java:419 clojure.lang.Var.invoke
                 AFn.java:163 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
                 Var.java:532 clojure.lang.Var.applyTo
                 main.java:37 clojure.main.main
```

Comment: You should show the code. I don't know clojurescript only clojure, but from the error it look like you put something like `(let ((foo "bar")) ..` and it should be `(let [foo "bar"] ..`

Comment: Also having a `(defn foo (bar) .. )` as opposed to a `(defn foo [bar] .. )`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler should ideally emit a line number for your syntax error. Somewhere you have a malformed let expression.

Comment: I have posted the complete stacktrace above.

Comment: Suffering a very similar issue here - the origin of my stack strace is reflected as `NO_SOURCE_FILE:1`